# Issue creating networkload balancer with Terraform

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

I have created couple of Ec2 instances in multiple subnets and assigned 4 secondary Ips to default ENI(device 0)- now the output of the aws_network_interface of private_ips attribute is giving all IP's including the host-private ip and other secondary Ip's randomly.

Now my problem is I need to exclude the "host private ip" and one ip which i assign to "windows cluster" from the output and provide the rest to create aws network load balancer. Is there an easy way to sort the output and exclude the required ip's from the List output? Here i am creating NLB with target by IP- so i need to provide the set of secondary IPs from each ec2 instance to create target group.

code:

```
resource "aws_instance" "web_servers" {
  count="2"
  ami                         = "ami-0a9ca0496f746e6e0"        # us-west-2
  instance_type               = "${var.instance_type}" # ="t2.medium"

  #associate_public_ip_address = "true"
  #user_data                   = ""

  network_interface {
    network_interface_id = "${element(aws_network_interface.foo.*.id,count.index}"
    device_index         = 0
  }
}

resource "aws_network_interface" "foo" {
  count="${var.instance["count"]}"
  subnet_id = "{aws_subnet.web_subnet.*.id[count.index]}"
  private_ips_count=4  
  security_groups = ["${aws_security_group.web.id}"]
}


output "priviate-ip-list"
{
  value="${list(aws_network_interface.foo.*.private_ips)}"
}
```

the output has whole list of private_ips including host private ip.
From the list I need to exclude 2 ips(one is host private ip and second one I will use for windows cluster") say here in the code I gave private_ips_count=4 (the output will have 5 ips for each instance).
so if I exclude 2 ips, I have remaining 3 from each instance.

outputs:

```
private-ip-list=[
  [
    [10.170.20.110,10.170.21.120,10.170.22.177,10.170.18.111,10.170.21.100],
        [10.170.150.10,10.170.152.44,10.170.151.11,10.170.150.11,10.170.155.10]
    ]
]
```

here  private ip of 1st ec2 instance is 10.170.21.120 
private ip of ec2 2nd instance is 10.170.151.11

so from the output i need to exclude 10.170.21.120 and additional 1 more IP 
from second set exclude 10.170.151.11 and additional 1 more ip.

from the remaining set
like from each insance one IP i need to assign to NLB target_id input to create a NLB. Here i am creating NLB with target by IP.

```
resource "aws_lb_target_group_attachment" "test" {
  target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.test.arn}"
  #target_id        = "ipaddress of 1 set [10.170.20.110,10.170.150.10]"

}
```

I am looking for ideas on how to save the Ip's and exclude the required IPs, and pass to parameter target_id with remaining ips

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It is (for me) very hard to follow your explanations. Providing the code probably helps..

Comment: Thanks Stephenking. I have added the code. please advise.

Comment: Can someone help with how to sort~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ output "priviate-ip-list" {
  value = "${list(aws_network_interface.foo.*.private_ips[0])}"
} ~~~~~~~~~~~as I  need to exclude one secondary private Ip.

Comment: Also is it possible to run the AWS cli command in Terraform and save to variable to compare with another output variable??

Comment: Is there a reason you want all these IPs on the same ENI? Might make it a lot easier if all the non default IPs were on a separate ENI

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how it will be easy if I have secondary Ips on 2 nd ENI? I am trying to configure windows failover cluster and configuring sql alwayson availability group.